# How to include a link with onclick in an alert that's not always visible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I have an alert that shows under some conditions. I want the alert to contain a link and execute some code when that link is clicked. However, I'm getting error "ReferenceError: doTheThing is not defined".

```
function doTheThing() {
    document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = "Done.";
    };

var alert = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"
role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Please
submit your wallet address or <span class="btn-link"
id=btn-donate onclick="doTheThing()">click here to donate your winnings.</span></div>';

var alertHTML = $(alert);

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = alert;
```

and html;

```
<div id=placeholder></div>
<div id=thing></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume: you defined the function in the dom ready context. If so, move the function outside.

```js
function doTheThing() {
    document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = "Done.";
};


$(function () {
    var alert = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"\
    role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"\
    aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Please\
    submit your wallet address or <span class="btn-link"\
    id=btn-donate onclick="doTheThing()">click here to donate your winnings.</span></div>';

    var alertHTML = $(alert);

    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = alert;
});
```

```css
.row {
    background: #f8f9fa;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
    border: solid 1px #6c757d;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" >


<div id=placeholder></div>
<div id=thing></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion, but can't get it working. Same error (looking in console) as in my OP (https://jsfiddle.net/kkoenen/fc7msLnb/4/). I'm doing something wrong..?

Comment: @KeesKoenen Answer and snippet updated, but I don't see any error in the console.  Can you elaborate?  Thanke

Comment: Please check this; it shows console now https://jsfiddle.net/kkoenen/fc7msLnb/4/

Screenshot : https://snag.gy/WRYAaG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your provided [example](https://jsfiddle.net/kkoenen/fc7msLnb/4/) change following settings:

[image]

As `Renan Souza` sad, it has to be included inside its own file.

Answer (score -1):

This code works fine:

```js
function doTheThing() {
    document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = "Done.";
};

var alert = `<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"
role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" 
aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>Please
submit your wallet address or <span class="btn-link"
id=btn-donate onclick="doTheThing()">click here to donate your winnings.</span></div>`;

var alertHTML = $(alert);

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = alert;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='placeholder'>
</div>

<div id='thing'>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, maybe he forgot to add the html elements, maybe he is not using this actual sample on his code, anyway this is not upon you to decide. Also, you cannot quote "It works fine" because I've not said that, and the actual code, even that slightly, is indeed different from the posted one.

Comment: Yes, I have both id's in my HTML. Editted question. Also, check this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kkoenen/fc7msLnb/4/  .. in console I can see same error I get.

Comment: @KeesKoenen for HTML elements execute javascript directly, it has to be included inside its own file, for example, in your fiddle, if you open up a tag `<script>` after the imports and put your function `doTheThing` inside the tag, this will work.
If you want to have it separate, then you need to change how you are building the HTML for the alert, use less HTML on JS part and more HTML on HTML part and add ids/classes, so you can reference then on JS to add behaviors.

Comment: I don't understand.. Can you please show how? https://jsfiddle.net/kkoenen/fc7msLnb/4/#&togetherjs=CNqn0t4beH